# Using PWR_OK to Activate an ATX Power Supply Automatically

Tags: power-supply, switches, atx

Okay so, I have an ATX PSU that isn't connected to a motherboard, and I'm currently using the simple paper-clip trick to ground `PS_On` in order to trick the PSU into providing power when I need. However, doing this cleanly means wiring in a switch to do this, but my PSU already has its own switch on the back which I'd like to just use instead, rather than two separate switches. Now, I know that simply leaving `PS_On` grounded all the time isn't really safe to do if I have devices connected.

But then I found out about the `PWR_OK` signal, which is a +5V logical high signal that is triggered when the PSU considers itself ready (shortly after mains power is provided).

What I was thinking I could do is somehow wire up the `PWR_OK`, `PS_On` and a ground pin, such that when `PWR_OK` goes to high, `PS_On` is automatically grounded to activate the PSU automatically, but safely. I may still put a toggle switch in there for good measure, but I basically don't want to be able to ground `PS_On` without the `PWR_OK` signal.

I'd very much appreciate any help in describing how to do this. Please treat me as a relative novice for any answer; although I'm comfortable soldering things, mostly all I've done is things like creating my own splitter or adapter cables for computers and even then, only simple ones. It's been quite a while since I had to design a circuit, work out what resistors I need (and where) etc.

Comment: You might like to consider [ATX Breakout Design](http://dangerousprototypes.com/docs/ATX_Breakout_Board_design_overview) - it doesn't address your idea directly, but maybe it will help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way a PWR_OK works, or at least the ones I have worked with, is by signaling the stabilization of the power output with a certain tolerance. This is used for sequencing purposes (e.g. When 5V line is ready enable the 3.3V PS).

This means you won't be able to use PWR_OK unless PS_ON is high first.

Comment: Ah! In that case I've misunderstood the specification. I'll probably have to think about what to do then, as currently I have no sequencing; as soon as `PS_On` is grounded my devices start drawing power; although my particular PSU seems to have a very stable supply, I want to make sure I don't fry anything :)

Comment: In that case (making sure you don't fry anything) the feature I have seen in some PS is the control over the initialization. e.g. increasing the capacitance on the Vref pin (if there is any) to create a longer "ramp-like" behavior on the output. This avoids major overshoots but it may delay your control loop, so be careful not to make it too large.

Answer (score 2):

As the other have posted, PWR_OK comes after PS_ON so what you propose won't work. However, there is no reason you cannot just leave PS_ON grounded all the time. For as long as a computer is turned on, the motherboard is keeping it grounded. You just want to make sure that you turn off the power supply before you connect or disconnect any load.

Comment: Uh, no, the computer does not keep the power supply on. It uses the standby 12v or 5v to turn the (rest of the) power supply on, when you turn the computer on. And you can hotswap loads at any time.

Comment: To clarify: the motherboard is always powered by +5VSB (stand-by), at least as long as the power cord is connected and the back switch is on. To turn on the rest of the power supply, the logic on the mother board (as powered by +5VSB), grounds PS_ON and keeps it grounded as long as the computer is on. When the motherboard ungrounds PS_ON, the power supply turn back off (again excluding +5VSB). As for my no-hot-swap comment, yes, the power supply is fine with adding and removing loads hot. However, this assumes the properly rated connectors...

Comment: The OP is talking about using a PS in a non-computer environment so I'm assuming he is not using such connectors. Thus, my connect.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand how ATX power supplies work, you *have* to pull down `PS_ON` to turn the power on, and then you get `PWR_OK` *eventually*. Without pulling `PS_ON`, you'd wait forever for `PWR_OK`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you really need to do anything to help protect the power supply or the motherboard from your PS on switch constant But if you wanted to do something that made any sense you could use two different relays and a momentary switch. You apply the momentary switch across the The circuit that I'm fixing to explain jumping them both out of so that you can apply ground to PS on what will be traveling through both of these relays switches is the ground to PS on.. connect the output of the 5v relay to PS on connect the input of the 5 volt relay to the 12 volts output connect the input of the 12 volt to ground use the proper voltages  to each relay so that they work correctly now you've made a series of relays that will stay on once you press the momentary switch but will shut off if either power rail has an issue The motherboard will still power up your power supply as normal if you've wired it directly to PS on But you're still faced with the same conundrum no way to turn it off if there is no issue with the power supply rails other than a kill switch You could make circuit with a PNP on The positive side of the 5 volt relays coil so with another momentary switch you could pull up the base of the PNP so that the power would stop flowing through it and turn off the system The computer itself when it turns off its ground would need to teed into the circuit also.. The circuit should float and shut off the system but you may have to add a very high resistance to 5v just to make sure... You guys seem like you can wrap your head around what I'm trying to say and I believe I got it all technically correct Good luck I hope this helps...